# In Tcl on Unix, how do I kill a background process that has been launched with exec?

Tags: exec, tcl, kill

I would like to launch a Unix background process from within a Tcl program by using Tcl's exec command. However, I'd like to programmatically kill the background process from the same Tcl program at some arbitrary time in the future. How can I best accomplish this?

```
bash$ cat loop.bash
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]; do sleep 5; done;

bash$ tclsh

% exec /home/dana/travis/loop.bash &
6598

% puts "How do I kill the background process started by the previous exec command?"
How do I kill the background process started by the previous exec command?

%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While in the tclsh environment, you should still have access to commands like [`ps`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ps_%28Unix%29) and [`kill`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_%28command%29).  I re-created your loop script and then went into a tclsh session:

```
$ tclsh
% exec /path/to/loop.sh &
22267% ps        
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
19877 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
22212 pts/0    00:00:00 emacs-x
22317 pts/0    00:00:00 tclsh
22319 pts/0    00:00:00 loop.sh
22326 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep
22327 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
% kill 22319
% ps      
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
19877 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
22212 pts/0    00:00:00 emacs-x
22317 pts/0    00:00:00 tclsh
22332 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

If you're wanting to do this from a tcl script, here is a short example which shows the results of ps after the exec'ed process has been started and then after it has been stopped:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
set id [exec /path/to/loop.sh &]
puts "Started process: $id"
set ps [exec /bin/ps]
puts "$ps"
exec /usr/bin/kill $id
puts "Stopped process: $id"
set ps [exec /bin/ps]
puts "$ps"
```

If your system has ps and kill in different directories, you will have to modify the script accordingly.

Comment: I edited the question to say that I'd like to programmatically kill the process in the future. The whole point of this is that I do not want to manually look up PID's and manually do the kill commands myself (on the unix shell, outside of the Tcl program.)  Sorry that I wasn't more clear about what I was trying to do.

Comment: @noneme:  I've edited the answer, adding a sample script showing how to do the kill from a Tcl script.  The minimum you'd need is the `set id [exec /path/to/other_program &]` and `exec /usr/bin/kill $id`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to kill a background process, assuming you saved the PID (in a variable called `pid` for the sake of argument):

### Run the [kill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_%28command%29) program

```
exec kill $pid
```

### Use the [`kill`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2367) command from [Tclx](http://wiki.tcl.tk/207)

```
package require Tclx
kill $pid
```

Both work. Both let you optionally specify a signal to send instead of the default (SIGTERM). Both let you send the signal to more than one process at once.

Answer (score 1):

The exec command will actually return the PID of a process it starts, which is clear if you RTM or try this on an interactive shell.

This can be used in combination with the kill command as suggested by GreenMatt.

```
% set pid [exec echo "hello" &]
25623
% hello
% echo $pid
25623
```